# Ubuntu 10.10 - 12.04 Graphical glitches

Tags: 12.04

When I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer and I log in, everything is just... Glitchy, and I have to re-install Ubuntu 10.04 off of a disk I have. This may have something to do with my drivers, as when I tried to turn wireless on it promted me to install some drivers. I didn't, and that may have been my doom when

Comment: I have realized it actually was my drivers. I really like it when things work out!

Comment: Have you installed your graphics card's drivers? Try openning the Dash and searching for Additional Drivers.

Comment: @user1610406 You might want to post your solution here so it could help others who have the same thing happen to them :)

Comment: @Bousie Already fixed :)

Comment: @Oyibo I have one reputation :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **System --> Administration -->  Hardware Drivers** and wait for the list of available drivers to load. When that loads, choose the preferred graphics driver and hit **Install.** After the driver is installed, restart your computer. When you log in, you should immediately notice some differences.